# Use PC internet on mobile phone via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, connection, mobile-phone, nokia-n-series

I want to use my Windows 7 PC's dial up internet with my cell phone (**Nokia N73**) via **Blutooth** connection.

Can I do that with some program?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The original document is [Here](http://web.singnet.com.sg/~kinston/Bluetooth%20Internet.htm) it contains screen shots as well as text. Text only posted here in case the link expires.

**How to setup an internet connection on Symbian phones using Bluetooth**
This tutorial is mainly intended for newer symbian phones like the 7610/6670/6260/3230/6630/6680/6681/6682. Guides for older phones can be found at http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/mraento/symbian/bt-ap.html or http://gnubox.dnsalias.org/gnubox/

Guide to set up your computer (HOST) (Windows XP)
I will describe using Widcomm (4.0.1.700) & BlueSoleil (1.6.1.4) here, you may have other softwares for your Bluetooth adapter.

You can download the BlueSoleil drivers at http://www.bluesoleil.com.
Latest Drivers Version
BlueSoleil -> 2.3.0
Widcomm -> 5.1.0.2800

1. Find out the COM-Port associated with the Bluetooth-Software. Under Widcomm software the information is located at Bluetooth Configuration -> Local Services -> Bluetooth Serial Port (sometimes as “ActiveSync?. Note the COM port. For my case, my COM Port is COM4.

Under for BlueSoleil software information is located at My Services -> Properties -> Serial Port A. Note the COM port. For my case, my COM Port is COM7.

2. Next you'll need to install a modem. Go to `Control Panel-> Phone` and `Modem Settings -> Modems ->Add`. Check the box `select modem manually?` And choose the `direct communication cable?` Now you will see a list of COM-Ports. Choose the one you looked up earlier. For my case, I will select COM 4 for Widcomm and COM 7 for BlueSoleil.

Note: You must insert your Bluetooth adapter before you configure the COM-Ports. If not, you may not see the COM Port you want for your serial connections.

After setup, you should see something like this.

Open the properties for the `Communications cable between two computers` that was created for the Bluetooth connection.
Go to the modem tab and set maximum port speed to max (115200). This will increase the speed from the default 19.2Kbs to 115.2Kbs.

3. Now we'll set up an incoming connection: At the Network connections page choose `New Connection Wizard?` Choose `Advanced Connection->Accept incoming connections` or just `incoming connection` (depends on your Windows version). Select the `Communication cable between two computers` that you have added just now.
   On the next screen, choose `Do not allow virtual private connections`. Now you'll have to add the user you specified in the phone settings. Also assign the password entered on the mobile. You may also choose to allow devices to connect without password. To do so, check the following after you finish setup on the wizard.

In the next dialog you are presented the network protocols. Open up the TCP/IP properties and select the `Allow callers access to the local network?` If you want to have the IP assigned by DHCP or manually is up to you. Windows 2000 users specify the IP range manually, since the DHCP feature doesn't seems to work. For manual IP settings, you can specify any range of your IP depends on your usage. Here I will allow four connections to my host computer.

4. You may now need to enable ICS if you are using ADSL dialup connection. For Lan connection, you may skip this steps. Go to your dialup network connection, click on properties, check `Allow other network users to connect though this computer's Internet connections`.

Click on settings. Enable the HTTP & HTTPS Server for NetFront or Opera to open page. You may add other services like FTP server, POP3 etc. if you use it on your phone.

5. Activate routing on your computer. Open up the Registry editor by clicking `Start -> Run` and type `regedit.exe`?

In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key:   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`

Set the following registry value:

```
Value Name: IPEnableRouter    
Value type: REG_DWORD
Value Data: 1 (Default: 0)
```

A value of 1 enables TCP/IP forwarding for all network connections that are installed and used by this computer.?
    ?
Quit Registry Editor.

Reboot your machine to apply the settings!

This completed the setup of your host computer. Next, read below for the setup on S60 phone.

Guide to set up your S60 phone using Bluetooth serial port

1. Download the corresponding version of GnuBox for your phone:
   a. 7610/6670: http://gnubox.dnsalias.org/gnubox/gnubox_6670.sis
   b. 3230: http://gnubox.dnsalias.org/gnubox/gnubox_3230.sis
   c. 6260: http://gnubox.dnsalias.org/gnubox/gnubox_6260.sis
   d. 6682: http://gnubox.dnsalias.org/gnubox/testing/gnubox_6682.sis
   e. 6630/6680/6681: http://gnubox.dnsalias.org/gnubox/testing/gnubox_6630_80_81.sis
2. Connect to your phone to your pc using the data cable. Double click the .sis file and install the application on your phone.
3. Launch GnuBox.
   Some configuration text will be displayed:
   ?(Loading CommDb settings)
   ISP ‘Bt?Not found
   ?/span>
   Create a CommsDB dump using the `Debug->Dump Full CommsDB` menu entry. The file appears as `commsdb.txt` in your C: (internal memory) drive. (Exact path is C:\Nokia\commsdb.txt) You can download this file using the PC suite. Save this file for your reference. It is not possible to automatically restore the CommsDB from this dump, that's why you may need to do a phone backup.

To do a memory backup, go to `Tools->Memory`, Choose `Backup phone mem?`
In this way, you can restore your phone memory back, if GnuBox affect your other connections.

Note: The below instructions are for 3230,6260,7610,6670. For 6630/6680/6681, please read the notes on the next section.

4. On your phone go to `Settings->Connection->Access points`. Select `Options->New Access point->Use default settings`. Apply the following settings (case sensitive!)

   a. Connection Name: Bt (older versions of GnuBox may need „GnuBox?span class=GramE>)
   b. Data bearer: Data call (on some devices gsm)
   c. Dial up number: 0000 (basically any number is valid as long the phone accepts it)
   d. User name: btdialin (or any other. But you'll have to remember it later on)
   e. Prompt password: no
   f. Password: bt (or any other. But you'll have to remember it later on)
   g. Authentication: Normal
   h. Homepage: none
   i. Data call type: analogue
   j. Maximum data speed: automatic
5. Now go to Options->Advanced settings and apply the following settings:

   a. Phone IP address: Automatic
   b. Primary name server: 0.0.0.0
   (For ADSL dialup connections, set DNS to the DNS of your ADSL connections. You can view this by typing ?span class=SpellE>ipconfig/all? under command prompt.)
   ?/span>
   c. Second. name server: 0.0.0.0
   d. Proxy server address: none
   e. Proxy port number: 0
   f. Use callback: No
   g. Callback type: Use server no.
   h. Callback number: None
   i. Use PPP compression: Yes
   j. Use login script: Yes
   k. Login script:
   CHARMAP [windows-1252]
   LOOP 10
   {
   SEND "CLIENT"+<0x0d>
   WAIT 3
   {
   "SERVER" OK
   }}
   EXIT KerrNoAnswer$
   OK:
   EXIT

(You may leave this blank as you can set this automatically under GnuBox later.)
l. Modem initialisation: None

6. Now leave the Access Points settings (your changes will be automatically saved). Navigate in the menu to the previously installed GnuBox software. 
   Once launched use the following steps:

   a. Options->set RAS login script (if you leave the login script blank at the Access Points settings. This will set the login script above for you.) 
   b. Options->auto set modem ID
   c. Options->create records
   ?/span>

(Now the settings of the AP you just created will be manipulated for our needs.)
d. `Options->2 Box Bluetooth->Serial port`.

Select your PC Bluetooth connection. 
When ask for `Do you want to require encryption`, select `OK`.
Close GnuBox.

At Widcomm make sure that you have enabled secure connections.
To do so,
`Bluetooth Configuration -> Local Services -> Bluetooth Serial Port`. Click on properties, may sure that `Secure Connections` is checked.

?/span>

At BlueSoleil, make sure that you have enabled Data Encryption.
To do so,
`My Bluetooth -> Security ->General`. Select `High` for security level, may sure that `Enable Data Encryption` is checked.

e. Next is to test your connections, under GnuBox, `Debug->Test comm channel`.

During this time, WIDCOMM on your PC will prompt you about serial port connections. Make sure that you allow the connections.

After the test, close GnuBox. Use FileManager, go to c:\nokia\ctest.txt and view this text file
Make sure that you got the following

```
123456Error = 0
78 Error = -3
```

This confirms that your phone setup is correct. If you got other error message, you may need to repeat the phone setup process again. Perhaps you may have miss out some steps. Ensure that your Bluetooth connection on your phone is always on during the phone setup

7. Once this is ok. Open Opera or NetFront and try to open up a web page. Now a dialog is presented to you where you'll have to choose a AP. Take “Bt?(or “GnuBox?. Now you should notice the Bluetooth icon in the system tray turn green (Widcomm only). Some seconds later an icon signaling a new network connection should also show up in the system tray.

Now you should be able to surf the web through the internet connection of your computer.

If not working, you may try to reconfigure your phone again. If you have a firewall installed on your PC there could be issues with making this work. If you have done all of the above and you still get DNS error messages using NetFront or Opera then try disabling the firewall and re-connect the phone to the network and see if it works. If it does, then look into your firewall software to see how to enable the Bluetooth network connection.

Instructions for 6630, 6680 and 6681
The usage instructions are exactly the same as 7610/6670/6260/3230 tutorial above, with the following exceptions and limitations:
You cannot set the access point 'Bt' to Data call when creating. You have only the option 'GPRS'. Set it to GPRS.
You don't have to enter a phone number while creating the access point.
If you need to enter DNS or IP address manually, these settings are ignored by default. You can click on Install -> copy from GPRS to activate these settings. Do this only after the entire setup (but for sure after ‘create records?.
If you need to set a proxy, make sure you enter this information when you create the access point Bt.
After clicking `Install -> create records` in gnubox, the access point will disappear from the `settings->access point` menu. It won't be available anymore. If you need to change proxy or DNS settings, do the following: click `install -> set to GPRS`. Then go to the `phone settings | access points`, apply the necessary changes. Then go back to gnubox, click `install -> create records`. You need then to click install -> copy from gprs unless you only changed proxy settings.
Built-in applications cannot access the access point Bt (and thus use the bluetooth internet connection). The internal access point selection dialog never lists the access point Bt. There are other applications which can use it, including for example IM+, Opera (go to the second page of the settings, select 'Connect to default access point' and select Bt from the list there), putty, vnc client, etc.
I do not have 6630/6680/6681 phones to create screenshots for this here. For more information, please refer to Xan’s gnubox forum.

Setup for Firewall
For ZoneAlarm, go to `Firewall -> Advanced`. You must set `This computer is an ICS/NAT gateway" to work`.

For others Firewall, you may need to find whether there is this option.

Comment: Quite a good amount of effort is required to write this details answer. Please accept a "Salute" from my side.

Comment: Link is expired now. Thanks for having the text copied.

Comment: @cfi - That's why I always do it, would be a useless answer now if it was just a link. Cheers for the acknowledgement.