# sharing internet connection to browse internet on my phone

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, internet-connection, connection-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use PC internet on mobile phone via bluetooth](https://superuser.com/questions/259075/use-pc-internet-on-mobile-phone-via-bluetooth)

I am connected to internet through a wireless network. Now from this computer i want to share this connection so that i am able to browse internet on my phone too. Is there any way i can do so ?

Comment: What data connectivity options does your phone have?

Comment: @Paul wifi,tethering(Wifi,hotspot)

Comment: Is your phone and computer on the same wifi network?

Comment: [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/424621/edit) your question & mention what phone you have & how do you want to share (wireless/wired).